# JQuery / Javascript error in IE8 when using fully qualified domain name

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, fqdn

This is incredibly strange and I can't figure it out. When using https://localhost/program/admin/menu.php I have no errors. But when I use the FQDN (https://FQDN/program/admin/menu.php), I get a javascript error. Here's the function that is failing:

```
$("#user-select").change(function() {
         var value1 = $(this + "option:selected").html();
    var attrs1 = value1.split("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
         applyValues(attrs1[0],attrs1[1],attrs1[2]);
    $("input[name=new-credential]").each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
    $( "#add-credential-form" ).dialog( "open" );return false;});
```

The JQuery function fails because the variable value1 is null. It is not getting the selected option text and I'm not sure why it would work when using localhost as opposed to the FQDN in the URL.

Basically, when the select box changes, the add-credential-form dialog is populated with the selected option's text and the dialog is openned. I have no problems in other browsers. Just IE8 when using the FQDN. If it matters, I'm using JQuery 1.6.2 and JQuery UI 1.8.15. I appreciate your help on this matter. Let me know if you need any more information.

Thank You!

Comment: @ppumkin Isaac is getting the html (so the text), not the value of the selected option. so `.val()` would probably get a different result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
var value1 = $(this + "option:selected").html();
```

to

```
var value1 = $(this).find("option:selected").html();
```

If this works, I don't know why it would work locally but not remote, though.

Comment: Thanks Ben and Chips. Sorry Ben, I can only give one check mark. This worked but it still doesn't explain why the orgininal code would work locally on IE8 but not remotely. All other browsers had no problem locally or remotely. Anyways, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look right to me:

```
var value1 = $(this + "option:selected").html();
```

Did you mean this?

```
var value1 = $(this).find('option:selected').html();
```